# Google Chrome Update Issue: Update check failed to start (error code 4: 0x80070005)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have been using Google Chrome for some time. It usually updates to the latest version when any new update is released by Google.

But now I am getting the following error:

[image]

And I am regularly getting error popup saying that:

[image]

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You have to provide us information about `KeyServer` because that isn't a Google feature.  This sounds like a job for your IT department.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks Ranhound. what it is about? this is the first time i am facing this since 2 years.

Comment: Ask your IT department.  They have clearly done something that prevents Chrome from performing an update.